# How to view .h264 video clip

Tags: camera, video

I have just acquired a Raspberry Pi Camera Board, and recorded a 5 second test video clip with

```
raspivid -t 5000 -o vid.h264
```

I am a complete novice with video, so I would please like to know how I can view this clip. If there is a general tutorial on video on the RPi, please could you direct me to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an command-line utility called `omxplayer` which will use the Raspberry Pi's VideoCore IV GPU to play video at 1080p resolution. Open up a terminal window (from the Desktop menu or by pressing Windows-key+R and then typing `lxterminal`). On the command line type `omxplayer vid.h264` and the video should play.

Comment: A brilliant answer, that (omxplayer vid.h264) worked perfectly, so thank you Phil B..I have marked this as the answer I wanted, but I would still like to read a general account of video on the RPi. If necessary I will ask this as a separate question.